# GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator Error 404

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

Currently I´m trying to run a Job in Apache Airflow. I have used many operators, but with GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator I´m having a 404 error.

This is the code use for this case.

I don´t know if there is some who could help me, I would be very greatful

```
import yaml
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.contrib.operators.bigquery_operator import BigQueryOperator
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow.contrib.operators.gcs_to_bq import GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator
from airflow.contrib.operators.bigquery_check_operator import BigQueryCheckOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from airflow import models
from airflow.contrib.operators.dataflow_operator import DataflowTemplateOperator
from airflow.contrib.operators.bigquery_operator import BigQueryOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago

configFile = yaml.safe_load(models.Variable.get("Createh3"))

project_id = project
staging_dataset = dataset
gs_bucket = bucket

sqhema =  schema

default_args = {
    'owner': 'familia',
    "start_date": days_ago(1),
    "dataflow_default_options": {
        "project": configFile['project_id'],
        "region": '-'.join(configFile['gce_zone'].split('-')[:-1]),
        "zone": configFile['gce_zone'],
        "temp_location": configFile['bucket_path'] + "/tmp/",
    },
}

dag = DAG(
    'write_and_transform',
    schedule_interval="@daily",
    catchup=False,
    default_args=default_args
)

start = DummyOperator(
    task_id='start',
    dag=dag
)

load_us_cities_demo = GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator(
    task_id = 'load_us_cities_demo',
    bucket = gs_bucket,
    source_objects = ['ejemplo/Ejemplo.csv'],
    destination_project_dataset_table = f'{project_id}:{staging_dataset}.samplesdos',
    schema_object = sqhema,
    write_disposition='WRITE_TRUNCATE',
    source_format = 'csv',
    field_delimiter=',',
    skip_leading_rows = 1,
    dag=dag
)

end = DummyOperator(
    task_id='end',
    dag=dag)

start >> load_us_cities_demo 

load_us_cities_demo >> end
```

Comment: Have you set the `schema_object` properly, [here](http://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.14/_api/airflow/contrib/operators/gcs_to_bq/index.html?highlight=googlecloudstoragetobigqueryoperator#airflow.contrib.operators.gcs_to_bq.GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator)? It should contain the whole path to a *.json* file where it contains the schema for the table, whereas `autodetect` must be false. I should point that you can use `autodetect=True` in case you are loading a *.csv* or *.json* file and you would not need to define the schema. Did it help you?

Comment: I have a similar problem, I get an error that it can't find the file, despite the file being in the bucket.

Comment: I have solved. The thing is that Airflow have an Issue trying to connect with logs folder so you have to follow the path to the log and see what coulde be the issue. I hope it help you.